# Coding of STM32H745 model via Simulink

Tags: matlab, stm32, simulink, nucleo

The "STM32H745" model is not among the models supported by the package named "Simulink Coder Support Package Using STMicroelectronics Nucleo Boards" available in Simulink. I am new in this work and I just want to make LED Blink application via Simulink. Can you tell me which tools I can use in Simulink so that I can improve myself?

Kind regards...

Answer (score 0):

If there is no support for this board, you can create the drivers with an S-Function or in a simpler way using an S-Function Builder block.